# Gene frequency problem

Tags: human-biology, genetics, dna

1/330 of white people in south Africa have a disease called Porphyri.

**What is the frequency of the gene if it is inherited autosomal recessive?**

This one I understand. The genotype frequency is $q^2 = 1/300$ so the gene frequency has to be $\sqrt{1/300}$ as it is inherited aa.

**What is the frequency of the gene if it is inherited autosomal dominant?**

Here's where I run into trouble. So if $p$ is the dominant allele and $q$ is the recessive allele the allele frequency has to be $2pq+p^2$ right? As we can either see them as $Aa$ or $AA$

But my book says it is $2pq+q^2$ and then solves it algebraically by pretending $q^2$ is so close to 0 that it's not in the calculations. I strongly disagree that $p^2$ is very small if I am right with my assumption. Which one is right and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you pretty much nailed the problem. If I understand correctly, you are just confused about the approximation that your textbook does, an approximation that is correct but not needed. Let me restate the solution to the problem first.

**Resolution of the problem**

As you said the frequency of sick people $\frac{1}{300} = 2pq + q^2$ in this case, where $q = 1-p$ is the frequency of the (dominant) allele causing the disease. It is a simple quadratic equation with one unknown so one doesn't even need to make any approximation to solve for $q$ (or for $p$). Rearranging the equation and expressing $p$ in terms of $q$ (p=1-q), you'll find that $q ≈ 0.00167$.

**Are the results intuitive?**

Note that the frequency needed to create a frequency of $\frac{1}{300}$ sick individuals is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{300}} ≈ 0.05$ if the allele causing the disease is recessive while it is only about $0.0016$ (31 times less frequent) if the allele causing the disease is dominant. It shows that indeed a lower frequency of a more dominant allele is enough to create more sick people.

**Is the $q^2$ term negligible?**

Given that $q ≈ 0.00167$, the term $q^2 ≈ 10^{-6}$, while the term $2pq ≈ 10^{-3}$. So, indeed the term $q^2$ is rather negligible compared to $2pq$.

Comment: You write 1/300 = 2pq+q^2 like my book. I say that it's 1/300 = 2pq+p^2 because p is the dominant allele and 1 out of 300 people has Aa or AA. 2pq + p^2. I don't understand why you have +q^2 in the end as we're not counting the recessive aa's ?

Comment: It is just a matter of what you want to call `q` and what you want to call `p`. They are totally interchangeable. In my example, I called `q` the frequency of the dominant allele causing the disease. But if you feel more confortable the other way around, you can call `p` the frequency of the dominant allele causing the disease.

Comment: Ah, okay, I thought it was the norm in literature to denote p as the dominant allele and q as the recessive allele, but I guess I am wrong. Thank you.